# dynamic importing components based on route

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I'm new to VueJS and I haven't found a possibility to load components based on route. For example:
page/:pageid
page/one
page/two

I have a component Page.vue
Within that component, I watch route changes. If the route is $pageid, then import and load component $pageid.

I've read this documentation: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html. But that's more focussed on lazy-loading. I don't see an example for dynamic importing and loading.

Regards, Peter

Comment: Dynamic components sound like exactly what you need.  Load whatever component by change the `:is` of the built-in `component` tag.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Dynamic Route Matching](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html#reacting-to-params-changes) of vue router, you can access the url parameters via the `params` property of the `$route` object. In your case it would be `$route.params.pageid` so you can use it to dynamically change the content base on the `pageid` parameter in the url. Also note that on url change from say in your case `page/one` to `page/two` the same component would be used, so you would have to watch the `$route` object change and change your content dynamically.

```
watch: {
  '$route' (to, from) {
    // react to route changes...
  }
}
```

Comment: Nice approach. You could also use the [Navigation Guards](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#navigation-guards) provided by the vue-router. Personally i would use the [In-component-Guards](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#in-component-guards) and react on `beforeRouteEnter`, `beforeRouteUpdate` and `beforeRouteLeave`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I already have the 'pageview' component where I watch changes on the route and I get the $pageid. What I want to achieve is dynamic registration AND importing. So if the url is page/one, then import one.vue and registrate it as 'page-' + pageid (so it becomes 'page-one') for example. 

When the url changes to page/two, it will try to import two.vue and registrate it as 'page-two'. 

This is how I got it done in my previous Polymer projects.

Answer (score 1):

> Vue allows you to define your component as a factory function that
> asynchronously resolves your component definition.

Since `import()` returns a promise, so you can register your async component by using:

```
export default {
  components: {
    'Alfa': () => import('@/components/Alfa'),
    'Bravo': () => import('@/components/Bravo'),
    'Charlie': () => import('@/components/Charlie')
  }
}
```

> Vue will only trigger the factory function when the component needs to
> be rendered and will cache the result for future re-renders.

So your component will be load only when it need to be render.

And you can use dynamic component to render it by using:

```
<component :is='page'/>
```

and

```
export default {
  computed: {
    page () {
      return 'Alfa'
    }
  }
}
```

If you already using `vue-router` you can directly use this in routes definition. See more in document [here](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/lazy-loading.html#grouping-components-in-the-same-chunk).

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [{
    path: '/alfa',
    component: () => import('@/components/Alfa')
  }, {
    path: '/bravo',
    component: () => import('@/components/Bravo')
  }, {
    path: '/charlie',
    component: () => import('@/components/Charlie')
  }]
})
```

As you can see this is dynamic importing but static registration (you have to provide the path to component.) which fit mostly in many situations. But if you want to use dynamic registration, you can return component directly instead of name see document [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#component).

```
export default {
  computed: {
    page () {
      return () => import('@/components/Alfa')
    }
  }
}
```